# OpenMVG mainComputeMatches.cpp input explanation

Tags: c++

How can i compute descriptor matches using --pair_list option file (using main_ComputeMatches.cpp).
What is the format of data in the file specified by input --pair_list?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must list the image view index.
See your sfm_data.json, each image is linked to a view index.
In the pair_list file you just connect the image pair your wanna try to compute like

```
0 1
0 2
1 2
1 6
...
```

Comment: Try to use openmvg-team[AT]googlegroups.com or github issue next time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding @Jack answer, you could also compact it like this:

```
0 1 2
1 2 6
...
```